# Convert AutoQuery query string to SqlExpression

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to re-create AutoQuery queries outside of a service request.  I am doing this because I give user option to save a request and then use that data elsewhere.  I save the query string data so I am trying to create a query from the saved query string.

I need 2 things.

1) query that returns the complete data not limited by default autoquery page size

2) query that returns the count

I tried making the query like this:

```
IAutoQueryDb _autoQuery = HostContext.TryResolve<IAutoQueryDb>();
var dto = new MyQueryDbClass();
Dictionary<string, string> pars = GetParameters();

var query = _autoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, pars);
```

The problem with this is that the query generated has the table name of the response object and not the actual table so it doesn't work.  Also I am unable to call `ToCountSatement()` on it.  It is also limited by my default page size.

Is there a way to convert the AutoQuery query string to a `SqlExpression` so I can execute it and also get count statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateQuery()` API returns a populated `SqlExpression<Table>` similar to what would have been created if manually constructing the query yourself, e.g:

```
SqlExpression<Table> query = _autoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, pars);
```

To clear the paging info you can call `.Limit()` without arguments which will clear any populated Offset/Rows values:

```
query.Limit();
```

The [Custom AutoQuery Implementations](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) docs shows an example of AutoQuery executes the query behind the scenes, e.g. you can get the total with:

```
var total = Db.Count(query);
```